# Facing this issue java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord Serialization stack?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am pushing twitter data through NiFi to kafka and process it with spark. The results are then written to elasticsearch, retrieve username, hashtags, time and few elements and write to Elasticsearch. Where could I be wrong?
I want to covert the results to dataframe and use case class for choosing few items from twitter json.

Many Thanks

```
package comSpark

import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer._
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
import org.apache.spark.SparkDriverExecutionException
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import scala.util.Try
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, LocationStrategies, KafkaUtils}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream
import org.apache.spark._

object TwitterAnalytics {
  
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ES").setMaster("local[*]").
                    set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")
                    val sc =   new SparkContext(conf)
                    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
                    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
                    import spark.implicits._

                    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(10))

                    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
                            "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
                            "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
                            "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
                            "group.id" -> "c1",
                            "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
                            "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "10000",
                            "zookeeper.session.timeout.ms" -> "10000",
                            "enable.auto.commit" -> "true")

                    val topics = Array("kafkaelasticproject")

                    val stream1 = KafkaUtils
                    .createDirectStream[String, String](ssc,PreferConsistent,
                            Subscribe[String, String]
                                    (topics,
                                            kafkaParams)
                            )


                    stream1.print()

                    
            //      })

                    ssc.start()
                    ssc.awaitTermination()
println(" stream completed" )

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) NiFi can post-process the messages as well as write to Elastic, why do you need Spark? 2) You should really be using **Structured** Streaming (streaming-kafka is deprecated) 3) Please include the full stacktrace in the question, not one line of the post title

Comment: And do you get the same error running the example? https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala#L36